# Login in C# and Microsoft SQL Server 2008

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am very new to the C# programming language. I code primarily in PHP/MySQL and have doen a bit of Java programming. 
I have created an admin table in my database that has just 3 fields, AdminID, username and password.

I am using Visual Studio 2010 as my IDE and have already set up my connector to the DB.

I have this so far in my C# code...

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (textBox1.Text == String.Empty)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Fill in your username");
                return;
            }

            else if (textBox2.Text == String.Empty)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Fill in your password");
                return;
            }

            //declare variables
            String user_name, passwrd;

            user_name = textBox1.Text;
            passwrd = textBox2.Text;

            //SQL select statement
            String statement = "SELECT Username, Password FROM Users WHERE Username = 'user_name' AND Password = 'passwrd'";

        }
```

My question is, where do I go from here...i.e. how do I execute the statement, see if a row was returned or not, hash the password input value etc in order to make a successful login script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use databases in C# , you should start looking at the [ADO.NET architecture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e80y5yhx%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

The easiest way to perform a read from a database is to use a DataReader, but the problem is there is no native ADO.NET provider for MySQL.

Here is an example with the [ODBC provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.data.odbc.odbcdatareader.aspx) you could use to read from a MySql DB (for connection string examples you can look [HERE](http://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql)

```
public static void ReadData(string connectionString)
{
    string queryString = "SELECT DISTINCT CustomerID FROM Orders";

    using (OdbcConnection connection = new OdbcConnection(connectionString))
    {
        OdbcCommand command = new OdbcCommand(queryString, connection);

        connection.Open();

        // Execute the DataReader and access the data.
        OdbcDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("CustomerID={0}", reader[0]);
        }

        // Call Close when done reading.
        reader.Close();
    }
}
```

If you want to use a native provider, you can use the [MySql Connector/NET](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-net.html) developed from the  MySql team, it should be structured as any other ADO.NET Data Provider, however i've never used so i can just point you to the documentation from MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

Please consider using a ready-made solution for implementing security with ASP.NET. Look into using the [Sql Membership Provider](http://www.asp.net/general/videos/how-do-i-set-up-the-sql-membership-provider) rather than rolling your own solution. The last thing the world needs is another insecure login implementation.

Comment: ok. Will look into it, but I was looking at this as more of a learning example than a login system I will actually use on an application.

Comment: Using a Membership provider is very much the correct way to do this because you can use it to authorize access to restricted parts of your site without any further coding. If you really want to learn about the **right** way to do it, consider doing this exercise in the context of rolling your own MembershipProvider rather than pursuing a completely independent approach.

Comment: I get you point. By the way, this is not for my website, it is for a stand alone payroll application.